# Clang command on windows exceeds line limit

Tags: windows, clang, llvm-clang

The command line limit for windows is ~7000 characters.  The clang command for my project is ~130,000 due to a very large number of includes.  Is there some way to tell clang about my project includes from a separate file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit to being curious why you have all of the includes on the command line, however, you can use this syntax to put all of the commands in a file:

```
clang @cmds
```

where cmds contains something like:

```
echristo@dzur ~/tmp> cat cmds
-c
foo.c
-o
foo.o
```

so the full process would look a bit like:

```
echristo@dzur ~/tmp> ls
cmds  foo.c
echristo@dzur ~/tmp> clang @cmds
echristo@dzur ~/tmp> ls
cmds  foo.c  foo.o
```

Comment: When you say you're curious that I have all my includes on the command line - is there somewhere else I should be putting them?  I'm rather new to C++.

Comment: Typically you'd use a #include for each header file a

Comment: Ah.  Well, this is a Unreal Engine 4 project.  There are #include lines in the headers AFAICT, but the cmake file has a lot of -I path/to/header statements.  I'm trying to use clang for autocomplete, hence specifying these statements on the command line.

Comment: That makes sense (sorry about the weird comment earlier, I guess it only partially came through).

And yes, -I lines will make everything quite a bit longer - especially if you have long directories leading to the headers. Still sounds like a lot of stuff on the command line, but this should get you going.